# Android fragments on back exists application

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, back

I am having a problem with fragments. I want to start a fragment when I click an item from a Contacts list and then, when I press the phone back button I wanna go back to the contacts list. The fragments starts, but when I press the back button it doesn't go to the contacts lists, it just exists the application and gets to the phone menu.

This is for the contacts list

public class ChatMainActivity extends FragmentActivity{

```
private static Button btnLogOut;
private static SessionManager sm;
private static ListView listView ;
private List<ContactData> contactsList;


private static class ContactListFragment extends Fragment
{
     public static Fragment newInstance(){
         ContactListFragment ourList = new ContactListFragment();
         return ourList;
     }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,final  ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contactlistfragment,container,true);
        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        btnLogOut = (Button)  v.findViewById(R.id.btnLogOut);

        btnLogOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SessionManager sm = new SessionManager(v.getContext());
                sm.logoutUser();
                Intent i  = new Intent(v.getContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });

        System.out.println("fetch" + sm.fetchContacts());

        List<String> nume = new ArrayList<String>();

        List<ContactData> contactsList = new ArrayList<ContactData>();

        for(String contact : SessionManager.getUserObj().getContactsInfo())
        {
            for(int i=0; i< sm.fetchContacts().size(); i=i+2){
                if(sm.fetchContacts().get(i+1).equals(contact)){
                    contactsList.add(new ContactData(sm.fetchContacts().get(i).toString(),sm.fetchContacts().get(i+1).toString(),true));
                    nume.add(sm.fetchContacts().get(i));
                }

            }
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, nume);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

                int itemPosition = position;
            //    String  itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

                      MessagingFragment cChat = new MessagingFragment();
                       ViewGroup parentViewGroup = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
                       System.out.println("Removed Views? ");
                       getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmentContainer,cChat).commit();
                      //  Intent i = new Intent(view.getContext(), MessagingActivity.class);
                      //  startActivity(i);

                        // Here is the tricky part

            }

        });


        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        // Here we set our custom adapter. Now we have the reference to the activity

    }

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chat_main_layout);

    sm = new SessionManager(this);
    if (SessionManager.getUserObj() == null){
        // We are checking to see if the Singleton object is set, if it isn't we must send the user back to login screen.
        Intent i  = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }

    ContactListFragment clist = new ContactListFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer, clist).commit();


}
```

}

and this is the fragment

public class MessagingFragment extends Fragment {

```
private EditText et ;
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    container.removeAllViews();
    container.removeAllViewsInLayout();

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.messaging_screen,null,true);
    et = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.etmessage);
    v.findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateMessageHistory(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText("");
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Init1");
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    et = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etmessage);
    view.findViewById(R.id.sendMessageButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateMessageHistory(et.getText().toString());
            et.setText("");
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Init2");
}

public void updateMessageHistory(String newText){
    TextView tv = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.messageHistory);
    String oldText = tv.getText().toString();
    oldText = oldText + "\n"   + newText ;
    tv.setText(oldText);
}
```

}

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: BTW, starting activity from onCreate() of another could create problems as onCreate() is part of the lifecycle management. Better wrap that code in Runnable and send it to View.post(). This is will enqueue the starting of login activity just after the current activity is initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Back stack is not turned on for fragments by default. But you can enable it easily. Try in your `Activity`'s `onCreate()` to replace:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, clist)
    .commit();
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
  .beginTransaction()
  .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, clist)
  .addToBackStack(null)
  .commit();
```

More info on Back stack:
http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/04/allow-navigate-back-through.html

Comment: I tried this but still not working. I doesn't do nothing now when I first click back, and when I click back twice it exists the application.